# Chromecast Custom Receiver to play premium content

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, chromecast, youtube-iframe-api

I'm working on ChromeCast custom receiver app and using the iFrame API for loading YT videos. The issue is that receiver app displaying "The uploader has not made this video available in your country" message when I cast the YouTube Premium content.

I think we have to execute some authentication process in receiver apps to access YT premium content.

1. How can I add authentication process in receiver app to play YT premium content?
2. Do we have any way available in YouTube or Cast or iframe API's to play premium content in receiver apps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible, as YouTube uses a cookie-based login system that can't be passed to the Chromecast in the way that, say, an oAuth2 token (for the API) can be passed. Without being logged into YouTube on the Chromecast, playing premium content is a no-go.

Comment: which means we cannot play premium content in cast receiver apps, is that right?... Then how come YT or Play Movies apps allowing user to play premium movie content in their custom receiver apps, I think that there could be a way definitely, but we need to identify the appropriate API details to do that, please keep posted here if you find anything related to this feature.

Comment: I've talked quite a bit with both YouTube engineers and Chromecast engineers; they're able to do it because Google owns both, and they can work together outside of the public API to make it happen. The solution they implemented for themeselves was one that isn't feasible for the public API, and as of last fall, they were still discussing ways to implement a better solution for the public (although it probably isn't high on their priority list ... you should submit a feature request to get it on their radar again!)

Comment: Thanks for the clear information, I will submit a feature request as suggested.